# NullPointerException with custom ExpectedCondition

Tags: java, selenium

I created a custom ExpectedCondition to be used as input in my wait.until() method, however when my code reaches my custom ExpectedCondition argument, a NullPointerException is thrown, and I cannot figure out why. I've tried everything, and the same result is always received. Below, you will find my code

CustomWait:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> visibilityOfElement(final  
    WebElement element) {
        return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver input) {
                try {
                    return element.isDisplayed();
                }catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
                    return false;
                }catch(StaleElementReferenceException e1) {
                    return false;
                }
            }   
        };
    }
}
```

LoginPage (this page contains the code that calls the CustomWait class method):

```
public class LoginPage {

    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;

    @FindBy(how=How.ID, using="email") WebElement email;
    @FindBy(how=How.ID, using="password") WebElement password;
    @FindBy(how=How.ID, using="submit-button") WebElement loginSubmitButton;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void login(String email, String password) {
        wait.until(CustomWait.visibilityOfElement(this.email));
        this.email.sendKeys(email);
        this.password.sendKeys(password);
        loginSubmitButton.click();
    }
}
```

When the program reaches the code "wait.until(CustomWait.visibilityOfElement(this.email))", that is when the NullPointerException is thrown, and I believe that the "WebDriver input" part of my parameter for the visibilityOfElement method of the Custom Wait class is where the problem lies, but I cannot figure out why.

Main(this is where my test is found):

```
public class Main {
    WebDriver driver;

    public Main() {
        driver = BrowserFactory.startBrowser("chrome",  
                 "http://123help123.com/");
    }

    @Test
    public void smokeTest() {
        HomePage homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, 
                            HomePage.class);
        homePage.clickLogin();

        LoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, 
                              LoginPage.class);
        loginPage.login("haha", "123");
    }
}
```

BrowserFactory (this is how my driver is created):

```
public class BrowserFactory {
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver startBrowser(String browser, String url) {
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC_OSX) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  
                                    "src/chromedriver");
            }
            else if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
                                    "src/chromedriver.exe");
            }
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) {
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);

        return driver;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, and if you need more information, then please let me know.

Comment: Why not use the built in [`ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got NullPointerException because you haven't initialized *wait* in your LoginPage class. So there is not driver to pass to your custom ExpectedCondition.

```
 public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
    }
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much, that was the issue! It's resolved now!